# How to get output parameters from stored procedure using sequelize mssql Node.js

Tags: node.js, sql-server, sequelize.js, tedious

how to get output parameter from stored procedure using node js
i can set input parameter as

```
 db.query(`usp_AmbulanceMap_Insert_Batch @VIN=${req.body.VIN},@BatchID=${req.body.batchID}`)
```

stored procedure is

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROC usp_AmbulanceMap_Insert_Batch
@VIN INT,
@batchID BIGINT,
@HexCode NVARCHAR(2) OUTPUT
```

i want to get the value of HexCode parameter But i get Error :

```
Procedure or function 'usp_AmbulanceMap_Insert_Batch' expects parameter '@HexCode', which was
not supplied.
```

Comment: You are supplying `@VIN` and `@BatchID` as parameters, but the procedure also requires `@HexCode`

Comment: [Sequelize doesn't implement this](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/7060), but [tedious itself does](http://tediousjs.github.io/tedious/parameters.html), so you could drop down a layer. (The link to the issue also describes an alternative: use a multi-statement batch with an `EXEC` and convert the parameter to a result set.)

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing the parameter `@HexCode` which is required.

If you only want this parameter as an `OUTPUT` make it an optional parameter like so:

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROC usp_AmbulanceMap_Insert_Batch
@VIN INT,
@batchID BIGINT,
@HexCode NVARCHAR(2) = NULL OUTPUT
```